# Desativar o botão submit por um certo tempo datetime do banco

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, datatable, id

É possivel fazer 1 submit por dia pelo tempo datitime do banco?
Ex; o iduser fazer um post por dia?

grato!

Comment: Se for implementar o faça no back-end. Se o fizer no front-end, devido a natureza do javascript, o usuário poderá reverter o bloqueio.

Comment: @Wiliams! Tudo em IT é possível!  Voçe deve colocar a tua pergunta de forma a ter responta de como implementar essa solução. E já agora, sempre que possível faça validações ao nível do servidor / backend.

Comment: sim é totalmente possível, mas a resposta seria ampla demais, primeiro comece pesquisando como gravar no banco a data por usuário e como ler, isso já vai dar um bom código em php, depois parta para a parte de fazer a parte javascript, que seria receber essa data ou um "true/false" para desabilitar o botão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para alcançar esse objetivo, podes usar essa solução:**

**Primeiro deves:**

- Criar tabela ***userSubmitControl*** com os seguintes campos: ***idUser*** e ***submitStatus***;
- Criar um script *(s2)* para verificar se o utilizador já fez post ou não. Isso, tecnicamente é verificar se o campo ***submitStatus*** é igual a *falso* (*false*) ou verdade (true).
- Criar um script para alterar o campo ***submitStatus*** para falso, caso este seja verdade, e este script deve correr todos os dias a meia noite de acordo com datetime do banco.

**Segundo:**

- Quando o utilizador fizer submit deves primeiro verificar através do script s2 se pode ou não, caso sim, prossiga com o submit e depois actualiza o campo para verdade; e, caso não, interrompa o submit e para todo.

***NB**: Podes usar a informação da tabela ***userSubmitControl*** para controlar o botão.*

Comment: show de bola isso ajudou

Comment: @Wiliames Boa! Então marca como aceite...